# batch file to find files with double file extensions and remove the last one

Tags: file, batch-file, rename, file-rename, batch-rename

I have several folders that have files with double file extensions along with regular file extensions. I need to create a batch script to search all the folders and remove the last extension with any files that have double extensions. None of the file extensions are consistent.

```
Here's an example

C:\test\regular.exe
C:\test\picture.jpg.doc
C:\newtest\document.doc.pdf

End Result I need

C:\test\regular.exe
C:\test\picture.jpg
C:\newtest\document.doc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET sourcedir=c:\sourcedir
FOR /r "%sourcedir%" %%i IN (*.*) DO (
 FOR %%n IN ("%%~ni") DO IF NOT "%%~xn"=="" IF NOT EXIST "%%~dpni" ECHO REN "%%~fi" "%%~ni"
 FOR %%n IN ("%%~ni") DO IF NOT "%%~xn"=="" IF EXIST "%%~dpni" ECHO CAN NOT REN "%%~fi" "%%~ni"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

This batch should accomplish the task.

For each file in the tree rooted at `sourcedir`, if the `NAME` of the file itself contains an 'extension' and the filename without the original extension does not exist, then rename the file. That way, if `...picture.jpg.doc` is found, the rename should occur only if `...picture.jpg` does not exist.

The command to rename is simply `ECHO`ed. You'd need to remove the `ECHO` keyword to activate the rename - after verifying that's what you want to do.

I've added a second line to report that a rename could not be done because of an existing file.. This could be done very slightly better, but it will work.

---

Revised to modify name in case simple rename can not be done.

Caution - this version will rename immediately - there are no `ECHO`es to provide a list first because it's nonsense to provide such a list when renaming a file may produce different results on the main rename run.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET sourcedir=c:\sourcedir
FOR /r "%sourcedir%" %%i IN (*.*) DO (
 FOR %%n IN ("%%~ni") DO IF NOT "%%~xn"=="" IF EXIST "%%~dpni" (
  SET renreq=Y
  FOR %%a IN (new alt extra another 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) DO IF DEFINED renreq (
   IF NOT EXIST "%%~dpi%%~nn_%%a%%~xn" (
    REN "%%~fi" "%%~nn_%%a%%~xn"
    SET "renreq="
   )
  )
  IF DEFINED renreq ECHO CAN NOT REN "%%~fi"
 ) ELSE (
 REN "%%~fi" "%%~ni"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Reasonably obviously, the list of "extras" can be extended if required.

Comment: I have a few examples where it cannot rename the file because there is already a file that exists. In those cases is there a way to rename it to something else? Example: File filename.doc already exists and the batch file tries to rename filename.doc.sh is there a way to rename it like filename_new.doc? I tried a few things but my syntax isn't correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and remove the `echo`, if the output is OK:

```
@echo off &setlocal
for /r \ %%i in (*) do (
    for %%j in ("%%~ni") do if "%%~xj" neq "" echo ren "%%~fi" "%%~nj"
)
```

Edit: added support for the entire HD.

Comment: Ooh - so close! But the destination name should be `%%~ni` or `%%~nj` (which should be the same) - `%%~Fj` will produce a syntax error with `REN` (but should be OK with `MOVE`)

Comment: @Peter - Oh, I always forget this `ren to full name syntax error` `:)`.