# How to rename files with special character in windows batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to rename all the files in a folder ( *.out.bmp) to (*.bmp) . Basically, I want to remove the ".out". 
I tried,

rename  *.out.bmp *.bmp

but this doesn't change the file names.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create batch file to rename large number of files in a folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808001/how-do-i-create-batch-file-to-rename-large-number-of-files-in-a-folder)

Comment: *.out.bmp is the same as *.bmp - they both end in .bmp

Comment: Look at string substitution.  Also, there is software that does a wonderful job of batch renaming.  Specifically for images, irfanview.com is at the top of my list.  Batch convert images and rename as well.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271586/rename-multiple-files-in-cmd

Comment: possible duplicate of [.bat file for renaming multiple folders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271107/bat-file-for-renaming-multiple-folders)

Answer (score 0):

The possible duplicate questions are technically incorrect.  The operation of batch renaming files in a DOS batch file is not what the question asked.  The question is asking how to use DOS to remove the second extension from a filename.

For example `file.jpg.new` should be renamed to `file.jpg` which is answered in this question [batch file to find files with double file extensions and remove the last one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486356/batch-file-to-find-files-with-double-file-extensions-and-remove-the-last-one)

The answer becomes

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET sourcedir=c:\test4
FOR /r "%sourcedir%" %%i IN (*.*) DO (
 FOR %%n IN ("%%~ni") DO IF NOT "%%~xn"=="" IF NOT EXIST "%%~dpni" ECHO REN "%%~fi" "%%~ni"
 FOR %%n IN ("%%~ni") DO IF NOT "%%~xn"=="" IF EXIST "%%~dpni" ECHO CAN NOT REN "%%~fi" "%%~ni"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Thus my input file is `SearchIR.yes.new` and the script outputs `REN "c:\test4\SearchIR.yes.new" "SearchIR.yes"`

Answer (score 0):

Using power shell:

```
powershell -C "gci | % {rni $_.Name ($_.Name -replace '.out', '')}"
```

Comment: Hi @mrudulaw if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.